# Why is the difference in the result of aggregate and tapply in R when using mean function

Tags: r

I am using a randomly generated data frame:

```
dat1 <- merge(data.frame(Gender = rep("MALE",5),height = sample(70:100,5)),
              data.frame(Gender = rep("FEMALE",5),height = sample(50:100,5)),by.x = c("Gender","height"),
              by.y = c("Gender","height"),all = TRUE)
```

when I use the `tapply` function, I get the result:

```
tapply(dat1$height,dat1$Gender,mean)
  MALE FEMALE 
  85.6   77.8
```

But when I use the `aggregate` function it results in:

```
aggregate(height~gender , data= dat1, mean)
  gender height
1 FEMALE   77.4
2   MALE   86.0
```

and the `by` function produces the same result as `tapply`:

```
 by(dat1$height,dat1$Gender,mean)
dat1$Gender: MALE
[1] 85.6
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
dat1$Gender: FEMALE
[1] 77.8
```

I know that I have used the sample function and I will change the value every time I execute it, but the difference in result is in single execution only.

Can someone help?

Comment: maybe it is just a typo but you used `height~gender` and not `Gender`for the `aggregate`. And I can not reproduce your error. Can you give the exact data with the difference?

Comment: Clear objects from the workspace (Environment). Correct gender by Gender in the `aggregate` function, and you will see that the results are the same.